# jquery mobile display page for 5 seconds then redirect

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-mobile, redirect

I am building a mobile website using jQuery Mobile and I want to display a page for like 5 seconds and then have it automatically re direct you to the next page.

I saw this code on the internet but I don't think it applies to jQuery Mobile:

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV=Refresh CONTENT="10; URL=index.html/">
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Oh sorry i dont know what happened...i put it in there      <META HTTP-EQUIV=Refresh CONTENT="10; URL=index.html/">

Comment: checkout this one http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.3.0/docs/examples/redirect/
This might help you

Comment: the code you found applies to everything, and doesn't need any JS.

Comment: Are you putting all your jQM pages in one HTML file, or separate files? Are you using the default AJAX navigation scheme?

Comment: it is one long html file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).delegate('#registrationCon', 'pageinit', function() {
console.log("testing again!");
setTimeout("window.location.href='#homePage';", 7000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would this:

```
setInterval(function(){ //redirect function; }, 5000);
```

Comment: im not very good at js...how would i reference the current page and the page to go to next

Comment: If you want redirect in each page you must this code 

´setInterval(function(){ window.location.pathname = 'newPage'; }, 5000);´